# Libre Office is lagging every ~7 seconds

Tags: libreoffice

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Libre Office there which is lagging every ~7 seconds and stun for 2-3 seconds.
Absolutely unreal working with office.
I suppose the issue linked with nvidia drivers but updating of it didn't help.

Here is `free` output:
total:      16086508
used:       4921596
free:       5560720
shared:     1097988
buff/cache: 5604192
available:  9722320

Also Nvidia driver info:
NVIDIA-SMI 535.129.03             Driver Version: 535.129.03   CUDA Version: 12.2

LibreOffice info:
Version: 7.3.7.2 / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 30(Build:2)
CPU threads: 12; OS: Linux 6.2; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Ubuntu package version: 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.4
Calc: threaded

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1498037/edit) your question and add more details to it like what version of the NVIDIA drivers that you have installed.  Also, what version of LibreOffice you have installed as well as if it is the snap or apt version.  More details you can add will help us help you!  Thank you!

Comment: How much RAM/swap do you have? `free` will tell you. `uptime` will hint at how busy your system is. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Are you using proprietary drivers or open source? There are settings inside LiberOffice in Options, View,  you can uncheck font anti-aliasing and font preview (font preview will be plain after that). You can also uncheckf Java under the advanced section there. That will loosen it up, but if you are doing heavy graphics/fonts, you will have to have a good working nvidia proprietary driver.

Comment: I added which drivers I use to main post. But I don't use any custom fonts. Just plain text, just basic calculation.

Comment: uname -a and post that kernel version. I think you have a nvidia driver issue as well. Look at this https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/latest-linux-driver-535-129-03-is-cuda-12-2/271589 and let me know what you think, because I'm still learning about this as well.

Comment: @Nishnabe, uname -a returns this one: Linux dqPC 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. Also need to mention that laggin excel and word. Even if there is no letters/numbers in cells..Also I tried to updated nvidida drivers and problems still alive....

Comment: Seems solved by going to NVidia settings - PRIME Profiles, switched to NVIDIA (Perfomance mode). Thank you all.